Where did Jochebed get the Bitumen?
Where did Jochebed (the mother of moses) get the good bitumen/tar/pitch/asphalt from? I once read that its not occuring naturally in Egypt or at the Nile, cant find that source anymore. On the other hand Irving Finkle made a coracle a few years back using ancient methods and it actually sunk bc the egyptian bitumen was lower grade bitumen.

Hi there, we wish you had that source. Do you have a link to the Irving Finkle referene you made? All links to a source really help. Also you should include the verse from Exodus 2:3 perhaps to help anyone see exactly what you are referring to :)

no matter the result of modern experiment, the ancient construction can still be better. However, these details are evidently narrative aspects of the stories very common in ancient narratives. Should not be taken literally.

@Michael16 I don't see any reason to disregard this minor detail. Might not be the most significant thing to ask a question about. But it is an interesting one. Looked up some egyptian tree texts... yes they had texts about it. Crazy cool stuff how they had significance on types of wood ... rambles on

Well let's look at the original verse...

Exodus 2:3
וְלֹא־יָכְלָ֣ה עוֹד֮ הַצְּפִינוֹ֒ וַתִּֽקַּֽח־לוֹ֙ תֵּ֣בַת גֹּ֔מֶא וַתַּחְמְרָ֥הֿ בַחֵמָ֖ר וּבַזָּ֑פֶת וַתָּ֤שֶׂם בָּהּ֙ אֶת־הַיֶּ֔לֶד וַתָּ֥שֶׂם בַּסּ֖וּף עַל־שְׂפַ֥ת הַיְאֹֽר׃
When she could hide him no longer, she got a wicker basket for him and caulked it with bitumen and pitch. She put the child into it and placed it among the reeds by the bank of the Nile.

Right so... Bitumen is usually called Asphalt (asphaltum) in modern times. It is a solid but when heated it is sticky and can be liquid. It is not "tar" even though we commonly call asphalt tar. Tar melts at higher temp, better adhesive. etc...
Bitumen was used in egypt for mummies. To the point where studies are about the significance of it, and not "whether or not" they used it.
The nearby dead sea is a rather famous source of Bitumen. (see this nifty picture/article)
So while this is not a definite answer, I imagine she likely could have obtained it "semi" easily within Egypt. It was used for waterproofing canoes, water transports, in addition to the previously mentioned mummification process.
It was processed by heating it until it melts and then "tweaking" it with different materials. Ochre, grasses, waxy or oily elements such as pine resin or beeswax.... (Source: https://www.thoughtco.com/bitumen-history-of-black-goo-170085)
So the verse said what type of Bitumen she used. She used Bitumen with Pitch.
What is pitch? Based on the wikipedia article about it, it was traditionally a pine resin.... Did they have pine? Honestly we don't really know. They probably did though. (Source of information and picture below: From mfth.journals.ekb.eg)

Now while a lot of Jewish slaves were busy hauling mudbrick and doing intensive labor, it is not unreasonable to assume that some worked on other "awful" jobs such as "waterproofing" a ship.
I don't see how it would have been difficult for her to obtain this material, and for a tiny basket not much would have been required.

Short answer: It appears to be a reasonably common material used in ancient egypt, it was unlikely to be difficult to obtain.

After reading your text, it appears to me that it wasnt difficult to obtain for her, even if it wasnt occurring naturally in Egypt. Thank you!

@andimjustso I didn't truly check to see if it was naturally occurring but it was widely used in egypt, so it must not have been that difficult to get.

Woah, Retroactive BH:SE stack exchange answer. Cool
